# Select all fonts in sketch - no plugin

Tags: sketch-app

Is there a way to only select the Font layers in sketch. I have about 80 different titles and want to change the colour or alter them in the way i want just by select only the fonts.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Without a plugin, the only option is to use "select all" and then use the inspector to change the type attributes.

Thankfully, Sketch keeps shape and type properties separate, so even if you have a number of shapes selected along with your text layers, modifying the text properties won't affect the shape layers.

Of course, this assumes you want to change all your text layers the same way and also only want to modify text-specific properties like type, color, and size and not layer properties like position or rotation.

If you're willing to go for a plugin, [Select Similar Layers](https://github.com/wonderbit/sketch-select-similar-layers) seems to cover your exact use case.